# Decrypting full disk encryption

Tags: encryption

I have latest nightly of cm12 (Android 5.x, Android M). Can I decrypt full disk encryption (which I know code of)? I have twrp and root, they should add support for that

Comment: Have you got cyanogenmod android M???

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, full disk encryption is a one way process, you will need to do a factory reset to get rid of it (assuming the cm guys took stock functionality, because that's how it works on stock).

Comment: I mean, that there should be some way to reverse it with root, but I might be wrong

Comment: To my knowledge, neither twrp nor clockwork mod actually support this functionality. There was a bug in cm for a while where you could not update the rom if you did full disk encryption,as twrp couldn't unlock it, (feature missing). You might have more luck sending an email out to the devs, maybe they will enlighten you further

Comment: CM is open-source :P